# Acid catalyzed hydrolysis of ester

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, esters

[image]

During acid catalyzed hydrolysis of ester why does the carbonyl oxygen attack the $\ce{H^{+}}$ ? Why doesn't the alkoxy oxygen which is more electron rich and less electronegative not attack the $\ce{H^{+}}$ with its lone pair? Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think that it is _more electron rich_?

Comment: Because one is sp2 hybrid while other is sp3 hybrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the carbonyl oxygen (red in colour) and alkoxy oxygen (blue in colour) is that the highly distorted pi-electron density (green shaded) towards to the carbonyl oxygen, due to more electro-negativity of oxygen that is the feature which is more on this oxygen than alkoxy oxygen . That feature provide the cavity for the H+ ion from acid, and the distortion of sigma- electron density at alkoxy oxygen is comparatively less than the distortion of  pi-electron density at carbonyl oxygen.

[image]